# Puzzle: What is the algorithm for finding the kangaroo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, puzzle

There is a kangaroo that placed somewhere on $L$ upon the axis of the natural numbers.

At some point of the time, The bell is ringing and the game starts: Each round the kangaroo jumps $K$ steps right on the axis (Means, that she moves from her old place $x$ to her new place $x+K$), And right after her jump, We check one of the natural numbers on the axis, by our choice.
If the kangaroo is there, we caught him and won; else, we continue to the next round.

We don't know the number $L$ - where the kangaroo been on the start of the game, and we don't know what is the $K$ - Which is the size of the jump (But we know that she always jumps $K$ steps right).

Find the algorithm which assures us that we always catch the rat after limited number of $n$ steps.

(Apologies in advance, English is not my native language).

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585477/leaping-frog-algorithm) for the frog version... (two hours earlier... Something going on?)

Comment: Do you consider $0$ to be a natural number? (It doesn't matter all that much, but it makes discussion of the problem easier if we agree what "natural number" means).

Answer (score 2):

You don't know $(L,K)$.  At each step, you can check one possible $(L,K)$.  For example, at step 2, you check $L_2+2K_2$; at step 3, you check $L_3+3K_3$.
Try to put all $(L,K)$ on one list, so you can go systematically through all possible $(L,K)$ pairs.